# Как обновлять дату

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Форма изначально невидима, открывается при нажатии на кнопку. В форме есть поля, одно из которых `input` в который нужно вставить дату (каждый раз при открытии этой формы, дата должна быть текущей, тоесть как только открылась форма, а у меня получается, что дата формируется при загрузке страницы и больше не меняется), выглядит так:

```
<el-form :model="Phonebook_user" label-width="140px">
              <el-form-item label="Users date">
                <el-input id="data_field" v-model="time" disabled/>
              </el-form-item>
              <el-form-item label="Users numer">
                <el-input v-model="Phonebook_user.numer"/>
              </el-form-item>
              <el-form-item label="Users name">
                <el-input v-model="Phonebook_user.name"/>
              </el-form-item>
              <el-form-item label="Users info">
                <el-input v-model="Phonebook_user.info"/>
            </el-form-item></el-form>
```

Для даты использую `time: this.getTime()` и сама функция:

```
getTime: function() {
      var dat = new Date()
      this.time = dat.toUTCString()
      return this.time
    }
```

И как потом эту дату добавить в класс Phonebook_user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял, что форма в эль-диалоге или невидима, пока что-то не произойдет? Попробуйте объявить в дате переменную и в компутеде (или вотчере) задать значение в момент, когда условие открытия формы выполнилось

Comment: @Andrey Ivasko, подправил описание, чтобы стало понятнее